# Python; comma at the end of old formatter argument list

Tags: python, formatting

Just a quick question:
What does a comma in the following statement does:

```
    print "Average = %s" % (avg,)
```

It seems I just can't find the relevant documentation.

Comment: with only one argument you dont need tuple type args. you can use simply `% avg`

Comment: @joaquin: Sadly, only if `avg` can never be a tuple. If it is (and its length is not 1, which should be the norm) you'll get a type error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes the argument list into a tuple. Without the trailing comma a single value in parentheses is just that value in parentheses.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do that before printing the value?

Comment: Not really, except that if you want to add more formatting arguments in the future having a tuple in place already is handy. See http://goo.gl/5CROC for more details on old-style formatting.

Answer (score 2):

It creates a one item tuple:

```
>>> x = ('hello')
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
>>> x = ('hello',)
>>> type(x)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 2):

The comma makes it into a tuple.

You could do either:

```
print "Average = %s" % (avg,)
```

Or without the tuple:

```
print "Average = %s" % avg
```

But the tuple means that it is easy to expand, for example,

```
print "Average = %s \n Total = %s" % (avg, total)
```

This is probably the reason this person used a tuple and only provided one argument. In the last example you can choose to add another trailing comma, `(avg, total,)` or leave it out. Either works.